# most pythonic way to retrieve images from within a module (in HTML)

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a program that sends a url request to a site which then produces an animation of weather radar. I then scrape that page to get the image urls (they're stored in a  Java module) and download them to a local folder. I do this iteratively over many radar stations and for two radar products. So far I have written the code to send the request, parse the html, and list the image urls. What I can't seem to do is rename and save the images locally. Beyond that, I want to make this as streamlined as possible- which is probably NOT what I've got so far. Any help 1) getting the images to download to a local folder and 2) pointing me to a more pythonic way of doing this would be great.

```
# import modules
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


##test variables##
stationName = "KBYX"
prod = ("bref1","vel1")                           # a tupel of both ref and vel
bkgr = "black"
duration = "1"
#home_dir = "/path/to/home/directory/folderForImages"

##program##

# This program needs to do the following:
# read the folder structure from home directory to get radar names
#left off here
list_of_folders = os.listdir(home_dir)
for each_folder in list_of_folders:
    if each_folder.startswith('k'):
    print each_folder
# here each folder that starts with a "k" represents a radar station, and within each folder are two other folders bref1 and vel1, the two products. I want the program to read the folders to decide which radar to retrieve the data for... so if I decide to add radars, all I have to do is add the folders to the directory tree. 
# first request will be for prod[0] - base reflectivity
# second request will be for prod[1] - base velocity

# sample path:
# http://weather.rap.ucar.edu/radar/displayRad.php?icao=KMPX&prod=bref1&bkgr=black&duration=1

#base part of the path 
base = "http://weather.rap.ucar.edu/radar/displayRad.php?"


#additional parameters
call = base+"icao="+stationName+"&prod="+prod[0]+"&bkgr="+bkgr+"&duration="+duration

#read in the webpage
urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(call).read()
webpage=urllib2.urlopen(call)
#parse the webpage with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlContent)
#print (soup.prettify())                            # if you want to take a look at the parsed structure


tag = soup.param.param.param.param.param.param.param    #find the tag that holds all the filenames (which are nested in the PARAM tag, and
                                                     # located in the "value" parameter for PARAM name="filename")
files_in=str(tag['value'])

files = files_in.split(',')                         # they're in a single element, so split them by comma

directory = home_dir+"/"+stationName+"/"+prod[1]+"/" 
counter = 0
for file in files:                                           # now we should THEORETICALLY be able to iterate over them to download them... here I just print them 
    print file
```

Answer (score 0):

I use these three methods for downloading from the internet:

```
from os import path, mkdir
from urllib import urlretrieve

def checkPath(destPath):
    # Add final backslash if missing
    if destPath != None and len(destPath) and destPath[-1] != '/':
        destPath += '/'

    if destPath != '' and not path.exists(destPath): 
        mkdir(destPath)
    return destPath

def saveResource(data, fileName, destPath=''):
    '''Saves data to file in binary write mode'''
    destPath = checkPath(destPath)
    with open(destPath + fileName, 'wb') as fOut:
        fOut.write(data)

def downloadResource(url, fileName=None, destPath=''):
    '''Saves the content at url in folder destPath as fileName''' 
    # Default filename
    if fileName == None:
        fileName = path.basename(url)

    destPath = checkPath(destPath)

    try:
        urlretrieve(url, destPath + fileName)
    except Exception as inst:
        print 'Error retrieving', url 
        print type(inst)     # the exception instance
        print inst.args      # arguments stored in .args
        print inst
```

There are a bunch of examples [here](https://github.com/niroyb/WebScraping) to download images from various sites

Comment: thanks as well. I'll check these out- they look promising, just will take a little time to thoroughly understand them.

Answer (score 0):

To save images locally, something like

```
import os
IMAGES_OUTDIR = '/path/to/image/output/directory'

for file_url in files:
    image_content = urllib2.urlopen(file_url).read()
    image_outfile = os.path.join(IMAGES_OUTDIR, os.path.basename(file_url))
    with open(image_outfile, 'wb') as wfh:
        wfh.write(image_content)
```

If you want to rename them, use the name you want instead of os.path.basename(file_url).